# Why is wrong constructor being called in parent class?

Tags: c++

When I create an object that inherits another class I want the constructor taking the same parameters to be called like in java.

```
class Shape {
    
    public:
    int width, height;
    
    Shape(){
        std::cout << "in def";
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    }
    
    Shape(int x, int y){
        std::cout << "in const param";
        width = x;
        height = y;
    }
    
    void toString(){
        std::cout << "\nwidth = " << width << ", height = " << height; 
    }
    
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{
    
    
    public:
    Rectangle(int x, int y){
        std::cout << height; 
    }
    
};
```

when I execute

```
Rectangle test(10, 19);
```

"in def" is printed. Why is this the case? Shouldn't the constructor taking the 2 ints be called?

Comment: `Rectangle(int x, int y){` should be `Rectangle(int x, int y) : Shape(x,y) {`, otherwise `Shape`s default constructor is called (hence the name _default constructor_).

Comment: No, it should not. [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language says that the base class constructor with no arguments is called by default. If you want to call any other specific constructor, you need to do it explicitly:

```
Rectangle(int x, int y) : Shape(x, y) {
                       // ^_________^ call base class constructor
                       //             taking 2 arguments
     std::cout << height; 
}
```

Comment: it's more general than a constructor call in initialization list.  if `Shape` would be an aggregate and there will be no `constructor` defined by user,  a  `Shape({0,0})` initializer would still work. Type name is used for simplicity because there is no other way to refer object of base class for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, what happens is when you inherit from a class, and an object of child class is created, it will always call the parent class and as for your case, what you need to do is use [Initializer list](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/initializer-list-in-cpp.php), you have to also explicitly tell that as rectangle is being initialized, shape will also be initialized like this:

```
class Rectangle : public Shape{
    
    
    public:
    Rectangle(int x, int y): Shape(x,y){
        std::cout << height; 
    }
    
};
```

Comment: that's not in all OOP languages, but modern ones act like that

Comment: yes i wasn't confirm that's why i wrote i guess, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

In C++ objects of base class are subobjects of derived class if virtual inheritance is not involved. All subobjects, both members and base classes are created first, in order of declaration. Base object would be first. This means, when you create a `Rectangle`, `width`, `height` will be default-initialized, a `Shape` would be created using default constructor, then `Rectangle` itself.

So if you add an output to `Rectangle`'s constructor, you'll see both.Your call to `Rectangle(int x, int y)` results in default-initialization of `Shape`. Default initialization for a class-type considers default constructor if one is available. One is defined by compiler if no constructors are provided.

As any subobject, base class can be initialized from initialization list in constructor of derived class, that's how another constructor for `Shape` can be called, see example below. Constructor calls can be delegated within same class this way.

```
class Shape {  
public:
    int width, height;
    
    Shape() : Shape (0,0) {
        std::cout << "in default c-tor\n";
    }
    
    Shape(int x, int y) : width(x), height(y) {
        std::cout << "in parametrized c-tor\n";
    }
 
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{     
public:
    Rectangle() {}
    Rectangle(int x, int y) : Shape(x,y)
    {
        std::cout << height; 
    }   
};

Rectangle r;
```

Output:

```
in parametrized c-tor
in default c-tor
```

Delegation is hardly needed in this particular case but in general allows skipping need to repeat same code in several constructors.